# How do I make sure that these background boxes are all the same size even with smaller images?

Tags: css

I'm building a features section of an e-commerce website and was wondering how I'd be able to keep the boxes the same size. They currently change depending on the size of the media but I want to keep all the boxes the same size. Currently looks like this depending on the size of the SVG. Alternatively, is it possible to make all the svgs the same size? [image: Sample]

```css
 #feature{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#feature .fe-box{
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow:20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) ;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  margin:15px 0;
}

#feature img {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#feature .fe-box:hover{
  box-shadow:-10px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) ;
}

#feature .fe1 h3{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:9px 9px 9px 9px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #97BC62;
  color: #2C5F2D;
}
#feature .fe2 h3{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:9px 9px 9px 9px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #FAD0C9;
  color: #6E6E6D;
}
#feature .fe3 h3{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:9px 9px 9px 9px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #c72d1b;
  color: #FDD20E;
}
#feature .fe4 h3{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:9px 9px 9px 9px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #97BC62;
  color: #2C5F2D;
}
#feature .fe5 h3{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:9px 9px 9px 9px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #97BC62;
  color: #2C5F2D;
}
```

```html
<section id="feature" class="fe-pad">
    <div class="fe-box fe1">
    <img src="/img/emptycart.svg">
    <h3>Buy Now</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="fe-box fe2">
        <img src="/img/freeship.svg">
        <h3>Free Shipping</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="fe-box fe3">
        <img src="/img/emptycart.svg">
        <h3>Buy Now</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="fe-box">
        <img src="/img/emptycart.svg">
        <h3>Buy Now</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="fe-box">
        <img src="/img/emptycart.svg">
        <h3>Buy Now</h3>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Comment: How do you want the suez of the boxes to be decided?

Comment: That's what I'm asking, I'm not sure how to keep them all consistent with different-sized images. Anything works!

Comment: I suppose what I’m asking is how do you want to decide on the height? Eg a fixed px amount, or a fixed percentage of the viewport height or…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the box's height:

```
feature .fe-box{
  width: 180px;
  height: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow:20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, .03) ;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  margin:15px 0;
}
```

Then by doing this, the button will be at the bottom of the image not the bottom of the box, what we can do is by adding:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

on the box, and:

```
margin-top: auto;
```

on the button styling

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep boxes at the fixed size you can try this code:

```
#feature .fe-box {
  width: 180px; /* Set a fixed width for all boxes */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  margin: 15px 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent content from affecting box size */
}
```

Now boxes will have a fixed width of "180px", and the content inside each box will not affect the box size.